# How to globally disable lazy loading in Entity Framework 7?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

It seems like this way is no longer available.

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lazy loading does not (currently) exist in EF7, so there is no API to disable it https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3797

Comment: do you know if there are any workarounds for enabling it? I've been trying stuff out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790533/how-do-i-simplify-the-access-of-a-has-many-relationship-with-the-entity-framewor