# How do I simplify the access of a has-many relationship with the entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Here is what I want to do:

```
var user = db.User.First(conditions);
user.Book.First();
```

Here is currently how I have to do that.

```
var user = db.User.Include("Book").First(conditionsForUser);
user.Book.First();
```

The reason why I want to simplify this, is because I don't want to have to specify what is included every time I want to access a relationship. Seems very cumbersome.

e.g.: I would like to just be able to do the following, given I have previously retrieved a user:

```
user.Book.First()
user.Blog.First()
user.SomeOtherHasManyRelationship.Where(conditions)
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
    public object RelationshipFor(string relationship)
    {
        using (var db = User.DbContext())
        {
            var relationshipType = TypeRepresentedBy(relationship); // unused for now, not sure if I need the type of the relationship
            var myTable = ((ICollection)db.Send(RelationshipName)); // RelationshipName is "User" in this instance.
            var meWithRelationship = myTable.Where(i => i.Send(IdColumn) == Id).Include(relationship);  // currently, myTable doesn't know about 'Where' for some reason.
            return meWithRelationship.Send(relationship);
        }
    }
```

And then how that would be used would be the following:

```
user.RelationshipFor("Book") // returns a list of books
```

I have some other logic in my code which abstracts that further which would allow me to do `user.Book.First()`.
Hopefully I can get permission to open source a lot of this, as I'm modelling a lot of the api after ActiveRecord-style crud.

Note, that I'm using I set of extensions I made to help dealing with dynamicness less painful: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/csharp-extensions

### UPDATE 1:

```
    public object RelationshipFor(string relationship)
    {
        using (var db = User.DbContext())
        {
            var myTable = (DbSet<DatabaseModels.User>)db.Send(RelationshipName);
            var myInclude = myTable.Include(i => i.Send(relationship));
            var meWithRelationship = myInclude.First(i => (long)i.Send(IdColumn) == Id);
            return meWithRelationship.Send(relationship);
        }
    }
```

For now, I've hard coded the cast of the user in an attempt to just get something working.
My error now is:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpressionN' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'.
```

Comment: I can cast myTable to `List<object>` and that gets me past the `Where` method not being available, but then `Include` isn't available

Comment: So, maybe my question is how do I dynamically cast to DbSet<dynamicType>

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial problem, and there's no "one size fits all" approach. What you actually seem to be after is [lazy loading, which was not included in EF7 for many reasons](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3312).

I don't know what the code you show is supposed to do, but one option would be to introduce a repository pattern, where you specify the "entities to include" at the collection level:

```
public class UserRepository
{
    private readonly IQueryable<User> _dataSet;

    public UserRepository(IQueryable<User> userDataSet)
    {
        _dataSet = userDataSet;
    }

    public IQueryable<User> Include()
    {
        return _dataSet.Include(u => u.Book)
                       .Include(u => u.Blog);
    }
}
```

And you can move lots of the logic to a generic base class, leaving you with just the `Include()` method. You can for example work with strings as you show (or enums, or ...), to only select related entities to include:

```
public class GenericRepository
{
    // ...

    public IQueryable<User> Include(string includeGroup = null)
    {
        return IncludeGroup(includeGroup);
    }

    protected virtual IncludeGroup(string includeGroup)
    {
        return _dataSet;
    }
}
```

And then in `UserRepository`:

```
protected override IQueryable<User> IncludeGroup(string includeGroup)
{
    switch (includeGroup.ToUpperInvariant())
    {
        case "BOOK":
            return _dataSet.Include(u => u.Book)
                           .Include(u => u.Book.Author);
        case "BLOG":
            return _dataSet.Include(u => u.Blog);
        default:
            return base.Include(includeGroup);
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var userRepo = new UserRepository(db.User);

var userWithBooks = userRepo.Include("Book");

var firstUser = userWithBooks.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == "Foo");

var firstUserFirstBook = firstUser.Book.FirstOrDefault();
```

One alternative would be to always include all navigation properties (recursively), but that would be a horrible approach in terms of query efficiency, as every query will be one massive join to all related tables, whether that is necessary or not.

Comment: I like the pattern, but the reason why I'm trying to do this dynamically, is because we have a database-first situation with over 200 models. So, making repositories for all of them isn't scaleable.

Comment: But what _do_ you want to do then? _"I don't want to have to specify what is included every time I want to access a relationship"_ - so you want to include all related entities? Or do you want to add lazy loading yourself to EF7? For your question, `Where()` doesn't work because you have an `ICollection`, not an `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: You're right in that including everything would just be a pain in the efficiency butt - but I think all of this should just be inferred.  Like, I should be able to have my `RelationshipFor` method handle the include, and re-loading of the parent model (not ideal to reload the parent, but it's better than including everything).  So, I should be able to do `user.RelationshipFor("Book")`.First()` -- at least, what's what I'm working towards.

Comment: I think I've made some progress. Updated OP